# RAILS ActiveRecord::Relation how to get many-to-many though: table name

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am in my quest of overriding activerecord method, but I need to be access the table name many-to-many relationship :through . How do i do it?

For example I have model Student and Subject, to connect the two I use has_many Subjects, through: :registers.

I have a statement Student.find(1).subjects, how do i get the table name register from the activerecord statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Student.rb

```
Class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :registers 
  has_many :subjects, :through => :registers
end
```

subject.rb

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :registers 
  has_many :students, :through => :registers
end
```

register.rb

```
Class Register
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :subjet
end
```

Make sure your associations added like this. And You can get your all subject lists by  `Student.find(1).subjects`

And You can also check entries in Register table by using `Register.all`

Answer (score 0):

You can access all the register records like below.

```
Register.all
```

Answer (score 0):

From your statement "Student.find(1).subjects", if you wish to get the registers along with the subjects details, you can do as:

```
Student.find(1).subjects.select("subjects.name, registers.name")
```